deploying code/changes to different environments in azure synapse using devops pipeline
I have three environments dev,qa and prod in azure synapse serverless, every environment have multiple databases and tables. I need suggestions on how to make these sources/databases dyanmic or parameterize them where user can pick a database he wants to make/push changes to.
I tried Azure datawarehouse extension but in Data Warehouse name i can only add one name, tried using variable there but the list of databases are too long to put there, so expecting somehow to link it to make it dynamic

Glad to see in Stack Overflow! May i know what have you tried for the deployment? Please share the definition, and json file(template and parameter) snippet and let us know what error you encounter. Please refer to the doc and link for the deployment process.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
